# Export PDF from a folder having multiple single mxd and mxd's having data driven pages

Tags: arcpy, pdf, data-driven-pages

I have folder having multiple single mxd and mxd's having data driven pages. I am trying to get the pdf's of each of these MXD's.if mxd's has a data driven pages then all the pages from a same mxd document needs to save in a single pdf.  What part of the below mentioned script will change so that it will consider the data driven pages.Right now this script is only exporting pdf from multiple single mxd document and not considering data driven pages. Need your suggestion for the same!!

```
>>> #Multiple single MXD's and Multiple datadriven pages in a single folder.

import arcpy, os

#Read input parameter from user.
#path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
path = r'Z:\Tier3\TrainControls\NonReportSpecific\2015_FINAL_PresentationMaps\MXD\REVISED\test'

#Write MXD names in folder to txt log file.
writeLog=open(path+"\FileListLog.txt","w")
for fileName in os.listdir(path):
    fullPath = os.path.join(path, fileName)
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullPath)
        if extension == ".mxd":
            writeLog.write(fullPath+"\n")
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
            print fileName + "\n"
del mxd
print "Done"
writeLog.close()

#exportPath =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
exportPath = r'Z:\Tier3\TrainControls\NonReportSpecific\2015_FINAL_PresentationMaps\MXD\REVISED\test'
MXDread=open(path+"\FileListLog.txt","r")
for line in MXDread:
    #Strip newline from line.
    line=line.rstrip('\n')
    if os.path.isfile(line):
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(line)
        newName=basename.split('\\')[-1]
        if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
            print "Basename:" +newName
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(line)
            newPDF=exportPath+"\\"+newName+".pdf"
            print newPDF
            if "DDP enabled mxd":
                ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
                ddp.exportToPDF(tmpPdf,"ALL")
                finalPdf.appendPages(tmpPdf)
            else:
              arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,newPDF)
            print line + "Export Done"
MXDread.close()
item=path+"\FileListLog.txt"
os.remove(item)
del mxd
BergenCountyLine_KeyMap.mxd

BergenCountyLine_SurveyAssets.mxd

Done
Basename:BergenCountyLine_KeyMap
Z:\Tier3\TrainControls\NonReportSpecific\2015_FINAL_PresentationMaps\MXD\REVISED\test\BergenCountyLine_KeyMap.pdf
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 612, in dataDrivenPages
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.pageLayout.dataDrivenPages)
AttributeError: Data Driven Pages is not enabled on this map document.
```

Comment: As it stands there is more than a code snippet included here which could lead to it being put on hold.  I think you should try and isolate out just that part which is giving you the error into a code snippet and focus your question on it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to replace this line:

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,newPDF)
```

with an if/else that uses this pseudo code:

```
if "DDP enabled mxd":
    "Export PDF of all pages"
else:
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,newPDF)
```

To do "Export PDF of all pages" I recommend reviewing [Combining Data Driven Pages with Python and arcpy.mapping](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/14/combining-data-driven-pages-with-python-and-arcpy-mapping/) where these lines of code will play a part:

```
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
ddp.exportToPDF(tmpPdf, “ALL”)
finalPdf.appendPages(tmpPdf)
```

Comment: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 612, in dataDrivenPages
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.pageLayout.dataDrivenPages)
AttributeError: Data Driven Pages is not enabled on this map document.

Comment: This is the error I m getting after replacing your code

Comment: Please make this an edit to your question rather than a comment here, but be sure to show us exactly the code snippet that you are running to produce the error.

Comment: Code updated in the question!!

Comment: @accedesoft I won't have time to look at this today and probably not tomorrow either but hopefully another of our volunteers may be able to. In the meantime I advise continuing to try and do it yourself, and to keep updating your question with where you are stuck if that changes.

Comment: I will keep on trying. I am not in hurry. If you have any thoughts please keep me updated.

Comment: @accedesoft Your snippet should be based on the pseudo code that I put in the answer.  The rest of the code is just a distraction to anybody trying to quickly help you.

Comment: @accedesoft I think I see what's causing your error. You put in the pseudo code PolyGeo gave you as if it were actual, working code. Really it's just designed to show what your code needs to do. You need to use something like arcpy.describe (http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//018v00000066000000) on each mxd in the folder (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000n000000) to see if it is DDP enabled, then if it is, you can run the code.